# How do I manage my hunger?

Tags: brogue

Perhaps I am spending too much time on levels and backtracking a lot, but I am having difficulty finding enough food to keep my nutrition up high enough.  And since I can't seem to be able to eat the dead, what other ways are there to gain food?

Comment: I don't think there's enough food in the game for all the quest rooms. The game is probably designed to to make you prioritize and pay attention to the food clock, especially if you want those lumenstones.

Comment: is it worth it to make a stash somewhere or should I just dump whatever I don't need so I don't have to back track to the stash often?

Comment: It depends on your strategy really. I like to get the amulet as quickly as possible (your nutrition loss is almost completely stopped once you get it), completely skipping a few levels, so you don't waste so much food. I find that Clairvoyance + Tunneling helps a lot because it can help you get around dungeons faster (saves you food) and avoid the bigger enemies. There should be food in just about every level below 26. Obstruction is useful for trapping monsters in poison gas. Blinking and stealth can work well for escaping, taking advantage of traps, and sneaking up on sleeping monsters.

Comment: It helps to know where you have leftover food, just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't keep the kind of a stash that you'll want to visit periodically - consumables aren't worth starving. Come back only for *great* gear that synergizes with some other great item you just found. If you're holding an armload of unidentified potions and scrolls, stand near some water and ID a few the hard way. At later depths, you'll appreciate being able to decide on the spot whether the consumables you find are worth keeping, using, or leaving on the ground.

Build your strategy around rings, enchanted items, and higher-quality items in roughly that order. E.G., your inventory is full, you've found a ring of wisdom, a couple staves, and platemail. Platemail is nice, but you don't own a ring of regeneration therefore a warrior build will have difficulty succeeding - dump any weapons and armor that you can't currently equip, don't come back for them without an exceptionally good reason. You need to keep exploring and finding new food with a minimum of inventory-juggling. Better versions of what you passed up can appear at later depths anyways.

I hope that helps! I die pretty often myself, but so far it has never been to the food lock.

Comment: what about back tracking to open up locked doors once you've found a potion of levitation or fire immunity so you can get the key?

Comment: @yx. Many factors can go into that. If you're on the same floor as the locked door, go for it. Other than that, generally don't go up more than 1 floor unless you have 2 pieces of food available.